# how i can true and false a value with ternary operator if that value is present or not in an array

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

i want an array of object with some properties and want to check that object have particular property  or not and moreover i also want if that object dosn't have that property in an array then return false if present then return true but i never wanna use if else statement i want to do it with ternary operator but i have some issue in below code inside a function.

```js
let users = {
  Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: true
  },
  Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
  Sarah: {
    age: 48,
    online: true
  },
  Ryan: {
    age: 19,
    online: true
  }
};

function isEveryoneHere(obj) {

  return (users.Alan) ? true : (users.Jeff) ? true : (users.Ryan) ? true : (users.Sarah) ? true : false;

}

console.log(isEveryoneHere(users));
```

Comment: I assume you want to check whether every user is `.online`, no?! `Object.values(users).every(user => user.online)`…?

Comment: Your function will return only one result `true` or `false`, what do you need? many `true` and `false` each one for each prop in accordance?

Comment: @deceze, it seems that he has a list with `online` users (they're all online)

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot to unpack here, but lets start with your user list.

When you store a list it is usually best to use an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), as this will give you access to the array methods like [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

Moving the "name" into the objects makes it nicely conform to array syntax, and you could use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get entries by name anyway.

Secondly, now that we have array methods, the ternary approach is redundant. We simply ask if every object in the list has a `true` `online` property. Doing it this way greatly increases readability of your code, and saves us from constantly reinventing existing solutions.

Here is an example of the above points:

```js
var users = [{
  name: 'Alan',
  age: 27,
  online: true
}, {
  name: 'Jeff',
  age: 32,
  online: true
}, {
  name: 'Sarah',
  age: 48,
  online: true
}, {
  name: 'Ryan',
  age: 19,
  online: true
}];

function isEveryoneHere(users) {
  return users.every(function(user) {
    return user.online;
  });
}
console.log(isEveryoneHere(users));
```

Comment: yeah you are right we can do it in this way but i actually want to use ternary operator in this case

Comment: Okay then. When you write that you `have some issue in below code`, what exactly do you want it to do and how does that differ from what it already does? Because your code looks like it's working.

Comment: yeah but the part of code in function if you look at it then you will come to know that i just tried to use ternary operator but i fail to code it properly so i said i have issues in below code